# How can i login into a private git server

Tags: git, version-control

I have to push a repository into a private git server, I have the email and password.

And I opened my Git-CMD in windows and entered these commands

```
git remote add origin xyz.git
git push -u origin master
```

but it showed me please complete authentication in your browser. and I pressed to continue and it opened a window in my browser related to my GitHub account but I want to push this project into the private git server.

How can I login into that private git server first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can authenticate via ssh if your server allows that
2. can try to update your password via windows credential manager
3. else you can try add remote https://email:passs@domain.com/reponame and hit command again